How to use APIs both loadFileUrl:allowingReadAccessTo: and loadHTMLString:baseURL:?
I need to load both the local source images and remote source images in WKWebView.
The url of remote images is a relative url.
To load the local images in WebView, I could use loadFileURL(_:allowingReadAccessTo:).
To load the remote images in WebView, I could use loadHTMLString(_:baseURL:).
But, I need both the local images and remote images.How can I do?

I used loadFileURL(_:allowingReadAccessTo:) api.
And, I replaced relative url to abolute url.
Sorry everyone. :)
